# ruby bsearch, find last occurrence

Tags: ruby

Is there a way to make `bsearch` return the last occurrence instead of the first?

For example:

```
arr = [1,2,3,4,4,5]
arr.bsearch { |x| 4 - x } # this returns the first 4

hash = {
  1 => {
    "foo" => "bar",
    "test" => "abc"
  },
  4 => {
    "foo" => "bar2",
    "test2" => "def"
  },
  5 => {
    "test2" => "abc"
  }
}

hash.keys.bsearch { |x| !hash[x]['test2'].nil? } # this returns 4, but I want it to return 5
```

I want to find the last occurrence where 'test'2 is not empty.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want the last occurrence of an element if they are identical?

Comment: If you wish to find last key `k` of `hash` for which `arr.include?(k) #=> true` and `hash[k].key?("test2") #=> true`, try this: `(arr & hash.keys).reverse_each.find { |k| hask[k].key?("test2") }`. That doesn't have anything to do with `bsearch`, however, so I guess I don't understand your question. Please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this Here in variable **y** we will store the last occurrence..

**hash.keys.bsearch { |x| y = x if !hash[x]['test2'].nil? }**

Answer (score 0):

You can reverse the hash and run `bsearch` against it. With your hash:

```
hash.reverse_each.to_h.keys.bsearch { |x| !hash[x]['test2'].nil? }
=> 5
```

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23221965/ruby-2-0-0-arraybsearch-behavior) will shed some light on how `bsearch` works.

Answer (score 0):

`bsearch` in the form you are using (taking a block that yields integers) does not return the first of the identical values; it returns any that it stumbles upon, as it thinks they're identical. For example:

```
[1, 2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 2.4, 2.5, 2.6, 2.7, 3, 4, 5].bsearch { |e| 2 - e.to_i }
# => 2.5
```

The returned value is somewhere in the middle of the `2.x` values, simply because `bsearch` stumbled upon it first. If you want to return the first value, you have to use the alternate form, where the block yields booleans. From there, it is trivial to rework it for last. For example:

```
array = [1, 2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 2.4, 2.5, 2.6, 2.7, 3, 4, 5]
indices = array.size.times.to_a
first_index = indices.bsearch { |i| array[i].to_i >= 2 }
last_index = indices.reverse.bsearch { |i| array[i].to_i <= 2 }
array[first_index..last_index]
# => [2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 2.4, 2.5, 2.6, 2.7]
```

If you don't need indices but the first and last element themselves, then this suffices:

```
first_element = array.bsearch { |e| e.to_i >= 2 }
last_element = array.reverse.bsearch { |e| e.to_i <= 2 }
```

---

For the hash part of the question though, your question is strange. For `bsearch` form where the block yields a boolean (as you're using in that example), it is mandatory that the block yields `false` for any element before the one you search, and `true` thereafter. (Similarly, when block yields integers, it should return negative values followed by zeroes followed by positive values. In other words, the array is supposed to be sorted with respect to the predicate being searched for.) So by definition, the last element that fits your criterion (all elements without `"test1"` are before all elements with `"test1"`) *must* be `hash.values.last`.